# Robotium test case with Gradle 0.9 and Android Studio, migration to Gradle 0.9 fail

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robotium, android-gradle-plugin

When installing Android Studio 0.5.1 I received the following message:

> The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.7.3).  Version 0.9.0 introduced incompatible changes in the build language. Please read the migration guide to learn how to update your project.

I have been trying to migrate my project and the app works just fine but I cannot get my Robotium test cases to run.

This is what I have tried:

> 1. Changed build.gradle from 0.7 to 0.9: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
> 2. Updated the gradle-wrapper.properties from distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip to distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
> 3. Following the guide at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09 that tells me to rename the testfolder to androidTest and to update test dependencies from instrumentTestCompile to androidTestCompile, i am now using androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'

My build.gradle file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 116
        versionName "1.5.5"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.foo.androidTest"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'
}
```

I do not know what I am missing and all I get when running is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.foo.androidTest.TestSimple$1
at com.foo.androidTest.TestSimple.setUp(TestSimple.java:47)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1740)
```

And in case you are wondering about the setUp method it looks like this.

```
45:    public void setUp() throws Exception {
46:            solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
47:            falseCondition = new Condition() {
48:                @Override
49:                public boolean isSatisfied() {
50:                    return false;
51:                }
52:            };
53:    }
```

I have not changed any java-code, all I have done is install Android Studio 0.5.1 and then tried to migrate to Gradle 0.9.

Comment: In my project, androidTest is under the foler src.

Comment: Also make sure you downloaded the latest Build Tools from the SDK Manager.

Comment: Make sure your test classes are at `src\androidTest\java`. This is where android looks for them by default if sourceSets are not overrided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something off in 0.9 gradle tool version

src\instrumentTest\java - works on 0.8.+ gradle tool version
src\androidTest\java - doesn't work on 0.9.+ gradle tool version